# Google Maps doesn't work on Android App with custom Google Maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I've created and Android app with custom Google Maps activity. In order to add Google Maps to my app I followed  [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).

As you can see I've added Google Play Services to my Android studio and installed Google repository, since in some similar threads on Stackoverflow it was recommended to install it.

[image]

After, I opened `google_maps_api.xml` and followed the link from this file in order to create an API-key. Finally, I created an API-key and inserted it in the string from `google_maps_api.xml`.

[image]

[image]

I didn't modify any other files in my project, since as I understood API-key will be automatically inserted in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

`MapsActivity.java`

```
package com.example.kirill.myapplication;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kirill.myapplication">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

However map doesn't appear neither on emulator nor on a real phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 with Android 7).

[image]

I think that I'm not properly using an API-key as there is some difference between debug and release key and I do not differentiate then at all.

**UPD:** It now works on a real device, but not on emulator.

Comment: Is the internet connected on your emulator?

Comment: @Hiroto Well, by default Wi-Fi is disabled, but I still can use Google Chrome and any other applications, even with disabled Wi-Fi, which require an Internet connection.

Comment: Last time I checked it will not work on emulator but works on a real device but that was in 2014. I hope this has changed in 2017. Can you test on real physical device?

Comment: Did you enable the Google Maps service on Google API Console?

Comment: @android_Muncher Whoa, now it finally works on a real device, but does not work on emulator. It really seems like the only issue is in internet connection. Thanks.

Comment: @Hiroto I've only added Google Maps Android API.

Comment: Try to use Genymotion. Its latest version supports the Google Play Services so you can develop the Android apps easily without a real device.